# Numerical integration: Composite quadrature - Conceptual derivation/ intuition

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, intuition, quadrature

In a text introducing basic composite quadrature rules (Simpson, Trapezoidal, ...) i read the following conceptual derivation for the general form of quadrature rules defined on $[0,1]$

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\ dx \ \ \ \textbf{(1)}$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \int_{t_{i}}^{t_{i+1}} f(x)\ dx $$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} h_{i} \int_{0}^{1} f(t_{i} + h_{i}\sigma)\ d\sigma \ \ \ \textbf{(2)}$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} h_{i} \ Q(f(t_{i} + h_{i}))$$

where $[t_{i}, t_{i+1}]$ are subintervals of $[a,b]$ and $h_{i} = t_{i+1} - t_{i}$.

---

I understand the substitution of $x$, but wouldn't the sum over the integral in $\textbf{(2)}$ without multiplication of $h_{i}$ equal $\textbf{(1)}$?

Where does the multiplication of $h_i$ in $\textbf{(2)}$ come from?

Comment: In (2) there is a substitution formula $x=t_j+h_i\sigma$; thus, $dx=h_jd\sigma$ and $x(0)=t_j$ and $x(1)=t_j+h_j-t_{j+1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $x(0)$ and $x(1)$? And are your subscripts supposed to be $_j$ and $_i$? And how does the multiplication of $h_i$ follow?

Comment: This is from the substitution rule for Integratals on the line. Since $\sigma$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and $x(\sigma)=t_j+h_j\sigma$, $x$ ranges between $x(0)$ and $x(1)$.

Comment: Reading about "Integration by substitution" helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the general integral
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx$$
If you apply the substitution $x=\phi(\sigma)$ then you'll get
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_{\phi^{-1}(a)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}f(\phi(\sigma))\frac{d\phi}{d\sigma}d\sigma$$
In this case we have $x=\phi(\sigma)=t_i+h_i\sigma$, $a=t_i$ and $b=t_{i+1}=t_i+h_i$ so: $\phi(0)=t_i=a\Rightarrow\phi^{-1}(a)=\phi^{-1}(t_i)=0$, $\quad \phi(1)=t_i+h_i=t_{i+1}=b\Rightarrow\phi^{-1}(b)=\phi^{-1}(t_{i+1})=1$ and $\frac{d\phi}{d\sigma}=\frac{d}{d\sigma}(t_i+h_i\sigma)=h_i$. In conclusion we obtain the following equality:
$$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}f(x)dx=\int_0^1f(t_i+h_i\sigma)h_id\sigma$$